# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'instance' and 'int' for pygame

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on a pygame and have encountered an error dealing with my health bar. When the enemies pass a certain point, I want the health to go down. The game will be similar to Galaga.

Help would be great. Thanks.

```
class Health:
     def __init__(self, x, y, health):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.width = 300
         self.height = 96
         self.velocity = 0
         self.images = pygame.image.load('health.png') 
         self.numimages = 20    
         self.cImage = 0
         self.health = 100  

def update(self):  

    #if collide1 == True:
    #self.health -= 25 
    if self.health > 96:
        self.cImage = 0    
    if self.health >= 92 and self.health <= 96:
        self.cImage = 1
    if self.health >= 88 and self.health <= 92:
        self.cImage = 2
    if self.health >= 84 and self.health <= 88:
        self.cImage = 3    
    if self.health >= 80 and self.health <= 84:
        self.cImage = 4    
    if self.health >= 76 and self.health <= 80:
        self.cImage = 5    
    if self.health >= 72 and self.health <= 76:
        self.cImage = 6    
    if self.health >= 68 and self.health <= 72:
        self.cImage = 7    
    if self.health >= 64 and self.health <= 68:
        self.cImage = 8
    if self.health >= 60 and self.health <= 64:
        self.cImage = 9    
    if self.health >= 56 and self.health <= 60:
        self.cImage = 10    
    if self.health >= 52 and self.health <= 56:
        self.cImage = 11    
    if self.health >= 48 and self.health <= 52:
        self.cImage = 12
    if self.health >= 44 and self.health <= 48:
        self.cImage = 13
    if self.health >= 39 and self.health <= 44:
        self.cImage = 14    
    if self.health >= 34 and self.health <= 39:
        self.cImage = 15    
    if self.health >= 29 and self.health <= 34:
        self.cImage = 16    
    if self.health >= 24 and self.health <= 29:
        self.cImage = 17    
    if self.health >= 18 and self.health <= 24:
        self.cImage = 18    
    if self.health >= 5 and self.health <= 18:
        self.cImage = 19    
    if self.health < 5:
        self.cImage = 19 
    if self.health == 0:
        pygame.quit()
```

creation:

```
health = Health(200, 0, 100)
```

Later in the while loop where the error occurs...

```
if enemy.rect.y >= 699 or enemy2.rect.y >= 700 or enemy3.rect.y >= 700 or enemy4.rect.y >= 700 or enemy5.rect.y >= 700 or enemy6.rect.y >= 700 or enemy7.rect.y >= 700 or enemy8.rect.y >= 700 or enemy9.rect.y >= 700:
    health -= 10
```

Comment: so, health is a Health() object, then you subtract 10 from it? Python doesn't know what you mean. Try health.health -= 10. That will subtract 10 from self.health, which is an int.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. New to python and been caught up with that for a while

Comment: btw: you could use `elif` and then you don't need all `and self.healt <= ...`

Comment: if `self.health` is 92 then true is `if self.health >= 92` and `and self.health <= 92`